# SharePoint on-premise app catalog configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, configuration

I have been tasked with recreating our existing SharePoint on-premise instance. Everything has gone well apart from a confusion I have with how the app catalog has been setup on our existing instance and from guides that I am using.

Now, in our existing instance, we have web app's such as

```
sharepoint - 80    http://server:80
sharepoint - 81    http://server:81
sharepoint - 82    http://server:82
```

Each web app has an app catalog that is a site collection in itself, so app catalog for first web app is `http://server:81/sites/catalog`.

In a pluralsight course that I am watching, there is another web app, which serves as the app catalog for the entire sharepoint instance (as far as I can tell), without a host header.

```
SharePoint apps
```

Our existing instance does not have this extra web app.

For the new installation, I have changed the web apps to

```
sharepoint - dev     dev.sharepoint.com
sharepoint - pqa     pqa.sharepoint.com
sharepoint - demo    demo.sharepoint.com
```

All web app's point to same port, and are identified by the host header. So do I need a separate `SharePoint - apps` web app? Or could I just use our existing way of each web app having its own catalog?

Also bear in mind that for dev, our SharePoint apps are updated on every build, whereas for pqa they are updated at the end of sprints, and for a demo they are updated at the end of releases. So all environments need to have their own versions of our SharePoint apps.

**Edit**

Just an update, I did end up creating a separate `sharepoint - apps` web app, but this is due to the fact that I am using a host header with existing web apps, and since app web url's are dynamic (and on their own domain), I had to create a separate web app with no host header. However, this is all this separate web app is doing. I am not using it as a central app catalog at the moment. So my question still holds.